# Positioning the menu of PopupMenuButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using PopupMenuButton in a flutter mobile app. I want to position the menu such that the calling button is centre aligned according to the screen. Below is how it currently shows on iPhone 12 Max Pro and iPhone 8. How can I get a consistent behaviour?

[image: iPhone 12 Max Pro]

[image: iPhone 8]

[image: How it should be aligned irrespective of the screen size]

Updating the post to include code. I have tried to play around with the offset property however I couldn't figure out a way to correctly calculate the size of the popup menu once the button is pressed.

```
return PopupMenuButton(
  elevation: 50,
  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.button,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
  ),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 162,
    height: 49,
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      child: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.button,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 16, 8),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              FaIcon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.lightPlus,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 16,
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Text("New", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.whiteLabels),
              Spacer(),
              FaIcon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.lightAngleUp,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 20,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  itemBuilder: (context) => [
    PopupMenuItem(
        value: 1,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              FaIcon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.lightEdit,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text('Type Text', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.whiteLabels.copyWith(fontSize: 16)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )),
    PopupMenuItem(
        value: 2,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.lightMicrophone, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(' Record Voice', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.whiteLabels.copyWith(fontSize: 16)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )),
    PopupMenuItem(
        value: 3,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.lightCamera, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(' Take a Picture', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.whiteLabels.copyWith(fontSize: 16)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )),
    PopupMenuItem(
        value: 4,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.lightVideo, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(' Record a Video', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.whiteLabels.copyWith(fontSize: 16)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ))
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I am sure only one thing will help you out here is the offset property of popup-menu.

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
  itemBuilder: (context) => [
    PopupMenuItem(
      value: 1,
      child: Text("Blashhhh", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      value: 2,
      child: Text("Blahhh 2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
    ),
  ],
  initialValue: 0,
  onCanceled: () {
    print("You have canceled the menu selection.");
  },
  onSelected: (value) {
    switch(value){
      case 1:
        //do something
        break;
      case 2:
        //do something
        break;
      default: { print("Invalid choice"); }
      break;
    }
  },
  child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 13.0, right: 13.0),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Text("Share it", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0))
  ),
  offset: Offset(0, -90),
),
```

Now as you can see I have set offset to -90 but you will need to calculate the width of screen based on that define the half to it and place the menu around that output and check.

```
double width = MediaQuery. of(context). size. width;
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: I went this route however I couldn't figure out how to calculate the width of the Popup Menu once the button is pressed to accurately calculate the offset.

Comment: @washfaq I don't understand why you need to calculate the width of popup menu to view on screen. But in build method I will used MediaQuery to obtain width and calculate the half of it. Which will set as offset for menu. And if you want to control the width of popup menu. I would suggest use of Container as parent to Popup menu.

Comment: To center the popup menu on the screen I will need to calculate the offset by (screenWidth - menuWidth) / 2. Unless I have the wrong idea.

Comment: I think its a wrong idea. To calculate the popup width. You can handle that using Container.

Answer (score 1):

try to share the specific code for more accurate answers.

However i think this can be solved by using [align] widget

Or else try with [center] widget

try with padding or mainaxisalignment or crossaxisalignment or safearea if possible.

reply back which method worked for you or how did you solved the issue.

Comment: Updated the post to include code. Align and Center won't help as the alignment is required for popup menu that appears once the PopupMenuButton widget is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

add the property offset  of popup menu

```
offset: Offset(-15, 10),
```

Answer (score -1):

Reusable widget PopUpMenuButton in flutter very easy:

[image: reusable widget PopUpMenuButton in flutter very easy]

```
very help helpfull for eveyr one 

    class PopupMenu {
         void Function(String)? onSelect;
         PopupMenu({required this.stringList,required this.onSelect,});
         final List<String> stringList;

         PopupMenuButton<String> createPopup() {
             return PopupMenuButton<String>(
             elevation: 0,
             icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
             onSelected: onSelect,
             itemBuilder: (context) => stringList!.map((item) => PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: item,
                child: Text(item),
             )).toList(),
         );
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the question was how to position the PopupMenu, not how to display it.

Comment: you need to add this  line in your code 
offset: const Offset(0, -380),

Comment: PopupMenuButton<String>(
      offset: Offset(-90.w, 0),
      color: AppConstant.themValue! ? const Color(0xff1E3242) : const Color(0xffF2F2F2),
      // offset: const Offset(0, 60),
      elevation: 0,
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        size: 25,
        color: pink,
      ),
      onSelected: onSelect,
    );